# <select> not redirecting to a url

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get my select tag to redirect me to a url that is in `option` value. For example this is my code:

```
<select #selectElement (change)="redirectToUrl(selectElement.value)">
   <option value="/add-product">Add a product</option>
</select>
```

And in .component.ts is:

```
  @ViewChild('selectElement', { static: false })
  selectElement!: ElementRef;


  redirectToUrl(url: String) {
    if (url){
      const urlTree: UrlTree = this.router.createUrlTree([url]);
      this.router.navigateByUrl(urlTree);
    }
  }
```

And ofc, when I select the option, nothing happens. I don't know what I'm missing...

Comment: Are you receiving the value in the redirectToUrl(url) method? Can you console log and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only one option the change event will never fire, as the option is selected by default. You can add a null option as a kind of placeholder when using a formControl that is preset to `null`:

```html
<select [formControl]="urlSelect">
    <option [value]="null" disabled>Please select</option>
    <option value="/add-product">Add a product</option>
</select>
```

```js
public urlSelect = new FormControl<string | null>(null);

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.urlSelect.valueChanges.subscribe((url) => {
        if (url) {
            const urlTree: UrlTree = this.router.createUrlTree([url]);
            this.router.navigateByUrl(urlTree);
        }
    });
}
```

You need to import FormsModule for this to work, and you should make sure to unsubscribe from `urlSelect.valueChanges` when the component is destroyed.

Comment: it's not necesary use a formControl always

Comment: @Eliseo Sure, but it does solve OP's problem, doesn't it?

Comment: Is over-complicate the problem. the solution is simply use:`redirectToUrl(url: String) {if (url) this.router.navigateByUrl(url);}` or `redirectToUrl(url: String) {if (url) this.router.navigate([url]);}`

Comment: What's that got to do with using formComponent? How does your code solve the problem? Feel free to add an answer, if you think you have a better solution, and I'll support it if it indeed is better.

Comment: ok.I just add a response. Yes. We can resolve a problem in several ways (and both correct). I only made a comment, apologies if this disturb you

Answer (score 0):

```
redirectToUrl(url: String) {
  if (url) this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
}
```

or

```
redirectToUrl(url: String) {
  if (url) 
     this.router.navigate([url]);
}
```